# Get AWS CLI autocompletion in windows cmder

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, aws-cli, cmder

I'm trying to configure AWS CLI autocompletion in Windows cmder.
I'm failling at the step of using complete command as bellow:
`complete -C '/usr/local/aws/bin/aws_completer' aws`

Is there another way to do ?
Here is the AWS documentation:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-completion.html

Comment: No experience with cmder. But can you run unix-like apps on it or is it just an emulator? The docs assume unix-like OS.

Comment: No it's an emulator, based on ComEmu terminal.

Answer (score 0):

For CmDer and PowerShell

1. Go to "vendor" directory, something like `C:\tools\Cmder\vendor`
2. Add to `profile.ps1` the following:

```
Register-ArgumentCompleter -Native -CommandName aws -ScriptBlock {
    param($commandName, $wordToComplete, $cursorPosition)
        $env:COMP_LINE=$wordToComplete
        $env:COMP_POINT=$cursorPosition
        aws_completer.exe | ForEach-Object {
            [System.Management.Automation.CompletionResult]::new($_, $_, 'ParameterValue', $_)
        }
        Remove-Item Env:\COMP_LINE     
        Remove-Item Env:\COMP_POINT  
}
```